# c# : How to set the opacity of particular row in same grid

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, checkbox, grid

I am silverlight c# devloper and i am under a situation which explained by snapshot below:

[image]

As you can see i have a grid (have to create prgramtically using c#, only option given to me).

And the first row(always visible) of that grid i have checkbox which on checking sets opacity of second full row to 0.3 and on unchecking it sets opacity of 3rd full row to 0.3 (all the three columns).

My try to do this is (probably wrong): (because it will create the opacity of whole childGrid not just row but i want the opacity row-wise on check and un-check of checkBox)

```
Grid childGrid = new Grid();
childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) 
{
    childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() {
        Height = GridLength.Auto
    });
}
CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
chb.Checked += (o, e) => 
  {
    txtblkShowStatus.Text = param.Parameter[index].Component.Attributes.Showstatus;
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    txt.Text = "Hello from second row";
    Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(txt, 1);
    // childGrid.Opacity = 0.3;
    childGrid.Children.Add(txt);
};
chb.Unchecked += (o, e) => 
    {
    txtblkShowStatus.Text = "No";
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    txt.Text = "Hello from third row";
    Grid.SetColumn(txt, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(txt, 2);
    // childGrid.Opacity = 0.3;
    childGrid.Children.Add(txt);
};

Grid.SetColumn(txtblkShowStatus, 2);
Grid.SetRow(txtblkShowStatus, 0);
childGrid.Children.Add(txtblkShowStatus);
```

How to achieve it any idea ? Any piece of code or logic for help is appreciated. **Or could you please explain if you have anohter logic to do achieve the same**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Grid childGrid = new Grid();

    Grid Grdrow1 = new Grid();
    Grid Grdrow2 = new Grid();            

    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    childGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        childGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
        {
            Height = GridLength.Auto
        });
    }
    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.Content = "Checkbox";
    chb.Checked += (o, e) =>
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "Hello from second row";
        Grid.SetColumn(Grdrow1, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(Grdrow1, 1);
        Grdrow1.Children.Add(txt);


        Grdrow2.Opacity = 0;
        Grdrow1.Opacity = 1;


        childGrid.Children.Add(Grdrow1);
    };
    chb.Unchecked += (o, e) =>
    {
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
        txt.Text = "Hello from third row";
        Grid.SetColumn(Grdrow2, 1);
        Grid.SetRow(Grdrow2, 2);
        Grdrow2.Children.Add(txt);


        Grdrow2.Opacity = 1;
        Grdrow1.Opacity = 0;


        childGrid.Children.Add(Grdrow2);
    };

    childGrid.Children.Add(chb);
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(childGrid);
```

Here is the example. 
In here I create two new grids for each two rows, and related text boxes added to the each row.then after that grids will be added to the child grid.

Then user check the check box 2nd row grid will be hidden and other one visible, then unchecked and do the opposite. You can change the opacity parameters.

Comment: Voilà Ça marche :) (https://translate.google.com/#fr/en/Voil%C3%A0%20%C3%87a%20marche)

Answer (score 1):

Where you are creating your `txt` children (it feels like the 80's again!) you could, instead of creating them and assigning them to a grid row/column, create them in their own grid that spans the parent grid and has the same columns. You can then alter the opacity of that row-grid.

The only catch is that keeping the width of each row-grid column the same will take some more work, but could be achieved by binding those columns widths to the actual width of the parent grid column width.

Comment: Another option is to fake it with a white (or whatever colour matches your window background) rectangle that spans your columns. When you want to make things less visible you increase the opacity of that rectangle.